# Hide GraphQL Operation names ('path') when erroring on production API

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql, dev-to-production

I am building a React App with a private graphQL API to access our backend/database. Because our API is still private, I do not want to expose my endpoints on Production. Unfortunately, when there is a graphQL error, it returns the following data to the network pane in developer tools:

```
{errors: [{,…}], data: {nameOfOperationDisplaysHere: null}
  errors: [{,…}]
    0: {,…}
      message: "Error Message!"
      locations: [{line: 2, column: 3}]
      path: ["nameOfOperationDisplaysHere"]
        0: "nameOfOperationDisplaysHere"
      extensions: {code: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR", exception: {stacktrace: [,…]}}
  data: {nameOfOperationDiplaysHere: null,}
```

Is there any way to encode/encrypt/hide those operation names on production so that we don't expose the names of all of our endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Apollo Server, you can use the [formatResponse](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server) option to provide a function for formatting the response before it's returned by the server. However, this is inadvisable as the path property is required by the GraphQL [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Errors) and with good reason:

> If an error can be associated to a particular field in the GraphQL result, it must contain an entry with the key path that details the path of the response field which experienced the error. This allows clients to identify whether a null result is intentional or caused by a runtime error.

Removing the path property will not prevent users from discovering details about your schema -- if a user can view the response, they can just as easily view the request that generated the response. Any queries made by your client will be embedded in your code as well.

At the end of the day, even turning off introspection is of relatively little benefit. There are much bigger fish to fry in terms of securing your service like authorization, rate limiting and depth or complexity limiting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apollo-server - you'll find required info in docs about [error handling](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/)